# Chrome Extension: How to persist data in popup across popup clicks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a selected text and show it in the popup.html (extension's).
I was able to pass the data using the message passing techniques of chrome extension api but everytime I click on popup, it clears the stored data.
So I thought of using the storage api. I managed to store the selected text using chrome.storage.local.set and retrieve it using chrome.storage.local.get.
But the data doesn't persists across popup clicks.

//Edit:
Adding all the files.

I figured out the issue. Apparently my attempt to save using chrome.storage.set is overwriting my previous value and not saving a new value.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
    var arr = Object.keys(items).map(function (key) {return items[key]}); 
    console.log(arr.length); // This shows the length as 1 everytime
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
        getMsg(arr[i]);   
    }
});
```

How do I not overwrite the value and save a new value eachtime ?

mycontent.js

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 67 && event.ctrlKey) {   // ascii C = 67
        getSelectionText();
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'setText', output: text});
    }
});
var text;

function getSelectionText() {

if (window.getSelection) {
  text = window.getSelection().toString();
}
else if(document.selection !="" && document.selection.type == "Control") {
  text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}

if(text != ""){
  chrome.storage.local.set({value: text}, logger(text));
  return text;   
}

}
function logger(text){
   console.log(text + ' saved123');
}
```

Popup.js

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
    getMsg(items.value);
});

function getMsg(value){

    var textNode =  document.createTextNode(value);
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.id = "textSpan";
    node.onclick = function(){
        callFunc(this);
    }
    var textBox = document.createElement("span");
    textBox.appendChild(textNode);
    node.appendChild(textBox);
    var element = document.getElementById('list-view');
    element.insertBefore(node, element.childNodes[0]); 
};



function callFunc(loc){
    removeTask(loc,outerDiv.id,true);
    loc.removeChild();  
}

function removeTask(id1, id, flag){
    if (flag != false){
        var pasted = document.getElementById(id1);
        var pasted = id1;
        alert(pasted.innerText);
        document.getElementById(id).value = pasted.innerText;
        id="";
        pasted.remove();
    }
}
```

Manifest.JSON

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Copy",
    "description": "current page",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
     "background": {
      "persistant": true
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": 
      ["http://*/*" , "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["myContent.js"]
    }
    ]
  }
```

Popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
     This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
     "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
     value "popup.html".
     -->
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Extension's Popup</title>
        <!--
          - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
          - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
          -
          - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
         -->
        <!--<-script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'>
        -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">    
        <div id="displayContent">
          <ol id="list-view">
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

I managed to send data across popup. But everytime I click on popup, data gets cleared. How do I make it persist across page refresh and popup clicks ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: Include a **complete** [mcve] duplicating the problem. Usually, this includes a *manifest.json*, some of  background, content, and popup scripts and HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You description is not sufficient for us to know what you actually mean by "click on popup". Does this mean click within the popup? Clicking on the button that causes the popup to be displayed? What? Be specific.

Comment: @Makyen Clicking on extension icon which makes the popup to display.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that we want to help. It is **much** easier to help if we do not have to recreate all the code needed to test (e.g. *manifest.json* and your popup HTML). This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even then, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @Makyen I have added all the required files.

Comment: Well, `set` is meant to overwrite, since it's a single value. How do you want to store data? As an array? As different keys? (your reading code suggests this) When do you want to clear that storage? What do you mean by "data gets cleared"?

Comment: @Xan I want to store data as different keys. Storage can be manually cleared by using the keys to access the data and removing their  respective values.