# How to use SessionStorage for a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Google Chrome Extension and i'm having an issue figuring out how to use the sessionStorage ability:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

This is the Code i have from the link above:

```
    /* Session Storage */
    sessionStorage.setItem('inputtextB', 'inputtext');

// Get the text field that we're going to track
var field = document.getElementById("field");

// See if we have an autosave value
// (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
}

// Listen for changes in the text field
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // And save the results into the session storage object
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.value);
});
```

"inputtext" is the textarea i want to save. I just want its current state to be remembered. As i understand this will make a copy of "inputtext" every time it changes and save it to "inputtextB", then if the pages reloads (But not closes) It will replace "inputtext" with "inputtextB".

my confusion is that i do not know how to make this work, I've been working with this all day and can't figure it out. I dont want this to persist if chrome shuts down only if i open/close the popup, or i reload the current page.

I have looked over a few things and these are close but i don't know if these are exactly what i want to happen.
[HTML5 sessionStorage or chrome.storage for Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501435/html5-sessionstorage-or-chrome-storage-for-chrome-extension) I think this might be the closest?
[Chrome Extensions - Saving Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277312/chrome-extensions-saving-settings)
[Chrome Extension: How to persist data in popup across popup clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627668/chrome-extension-how-to-persist-data-in-popup-across-popup-clicks)
I hope i can get a little help to figure out the best way to do this.

Edit:
What happens is you enter text Then you press a button and it parses it for use in HTML.

Example of how this works:
( Hi, how are you? ) and it outputs-

```
(<span style="color: #008080;">Hi</span><span style="color: #006400;">,</span><span style="color: #008080;"> how are you</span><span style="color: #006400;">?</span> )
```

When using Inspect popup this shows:
https://i.gyazo.com/9effdfac3e8b38ba7aa3908189ec50a4.png
since i added the above code whenever i press the button to parse this shows:
https://i.gyazo.com/7264a620eb6019302909e12675343870.png

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is with the currently used code. Make it more obvious. In case the problem is that the value persists after browser relaunches, you can explicitly clear the value when the window closes using `onbeforeunload` event.

Comment: @wOxxOm My problem is that i myself do not know what im doing wrong, when i inspect popup this shows: https://i.gyazo.com/9effdfac3e8b38ba7aa3908189ec50a4.png
Also whenever i use the button to push the text through this shows:https://i.gyazo.com/7264a620eb6019302909e12675343870.png

If i remove the SessionStorage code the button works fine, i believe im just using the code wrong.

Comment: The error you see is not related to the topic. It means the element does not exist when js script runs. Move the script declaration before the closing tag of the body element.